# Codeigniter Display a value in view html from a foreach php

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, ajax

I want to display a value back to the upper part of the page. 
Here is my code:
*line 127-138* *(this is queried in the model and displayed it in view)*

```
$time =  strtotime($row->due_by);

if(!empty($time)){
    echo $due =  date('H:i:s m/d/Y',$time);
    if( date('m/d/Y',$time) == date('m/d/Y')){
      $dtoday++;
    }

    if(date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$time) < date('m/d/Y H:i:s')){
       $drequest++;
    }
 }
```

I want to display results in *line 73-76*

```
<span><?php echo $dtoday;?></span>
<span><?php echo $drequest;?></span>
```

I declared $dtoday=0 and $drequest=0 already on the top part of the page, but it will only display 0 on the span.

Comment: Is your span in the loop?

Comment: no it's outside the loop,

Comment: that means both the condition if( date('m/d/Y',$time) == date('m/d/Y')) and  if(date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$time) < date('m/d/Y H:i:s')) are false

Comment: @CrystalGrace loop's increment just work in loop's body not outside the body.

Answer (score 0):

in code: line 127-138 only you are increment the value. but you need it before increment that is in the line of 73-76.

So you should write the code of lines 127 - 138 before the line of 73.
You should know the structure of code write.
that is like this first operations

```
 $dtoday=0;$drequest=0;
 $time =  strtotime($row->due_by);

 if(!empty($time)){
  echo $due =  date('H:i:s m/d/Y',$time);
  if( date('m/d/Y',$time) == date('m/d/Y')){
  $dtoday++;
 }

 if(date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$time) < date('m/d/Y H:i:s')){
   $drequest++;
 }
}
```

Then you should display/ print here

```
<span><?php echo $dtoday;?></span>
<span><?php echo $drequest;?></span>
```